# Exactly which word ‘triggers’ the use of "que" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

> - Je ne suis pas dans cette ville depuis dix minutes **que** je rameute déjà les foules ! (à cause de ma popularité !)

I think it has the same meaning as "et" or "mais". I understand that words like "tellement" are followed by "que", but exactly which word ‘triggers’ the use of "que" in this sentence?

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to *Le bon usage* from a recent edition, I would suggest you look at §1121a.

It basically states that the French language is not satisfied to put two propositions side-by-side without any visible/audible separation between them. In many cases, as here, the separation is incarnated by the addition of **que**.

> À peine avait-il son bonheur entre les mains **qu**’on voulait le lui reprendre.    –*Gustave Flaubert, L’éducation sentimentale*

The negation in your example also seems to play some role, since the positive version would sound more natural with **et** or **mais**, while either of the three (que, et, mais) could be expected for the negative version:

> Je suis dans cette ville depuis dix minutes **et** je rameute déjà les foules ! (à cause de ma popularité !)

Comment: Here's a similarly puzzling one that may be difficult to account for: "C'est un animal bizarre *que* le lion." Except that here we don't even have another proposition to link it; it's almost as if it replaced a comma. A French linguistics prof once told me it was probably just a quirk. :p

Comment: Same book, §717c. This one is presented as a relic from older times, on whose details grammarians don’t fully agree. _Le bon usage_ claims that this **que** would be an attribute introducing a proposition where the verb has been removed, though it would initially had been present in the auditor’s mind: “C’est un animal bizarre _qu_[’est] le lion”

Comment: Nice answer. Imagine the syntax that would create in the already highly redundant: "Qu'est-ce que c'est que le lion ?" :)

Comment: Could "quand" also be used to separate two "present" propositions like those in the OP's example or at least in those two "past imperfect" ones in the Flaubert example?  I ask because in English I think I might be tempted to translate the "que" in the Flaubert/imperfect example as "when," but using "when" in an English translation of the OP's example, where both propositions are stated in the present, would make it sound more like a weird and/or teenage narration of past events: "I'm like here for less than 10 minutes when, "Bam!" I'm already attracting crowds." Thanks and +1!

Comment: I don’t think **when** would mean the exact same thing. **Que** implies some sort of linked simultaneity, while **quand/when** breaks the link and simply puts the simultaneity forward. Because he gets in town, people gather, and very quickly (**que**). He had barely made it in town before people, for whichever unknown reason, started gathering, but obviously, when they did gather, they did it around the crowd magnet that I am (**quand**). It’s only my feeling of it, though. Someone could prove me wrong.

Comment: @Feelew _Que_ in your Flaubert example, _À peine avait-il son bonheur entre les mains qu’on voulait le lui reprendre_, is part of the idiom _à peine ... que_. And _que_ in the OP's quotation has a different function from that in the set phrase just mentioned.