# Nuances of meaning between "ce que c’est que de vivre" and "ce que ça fait de vivre"

Tags: expressions

> ... mais il ne sait pas **ce que c’est que** de vivre  sur une île isolée.
>
> {vs}: ... mais il ne sait pas **ce que ça fait** de vivre  sur une île isolée.

I myself would say "ce que ça fait" here, so I'm curious to find out about the difference in meaning between the two. Is it a variant of the expression "Qu'est-ce que c'est que ça ?"?

If so, I wonder if the first sentence serves to express a sense of frustration at his ignorance?

Incidentally, the function of "*que* (de vivre)" might be related to the following post:

[What is the function of “que” in the phrase “que de + infinitive” here?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26428/what-is-the-function-of-que-in-the-phrase-que-de-infinitive-here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. *mais il ne sait pas ce que c’est que de vivre sur une île isolée*:

As a native speaker I would literaly translate that to "but he doesn't know what it is to live on an isolated Island".

2. *mais il ne sait pas ce que ça fait de vivre sur une île isolée*:

Literally this could be translated as "but he doesn't know how it feels to live on an isolated island".

As you correctly guessed, both sentences serve to express a sense of frustration at the ignorance of the person referred to as 'he'.

However, in sentence 1. you could easily drop the second 'que'; it would still be valid French (as far as my experience goes) and doesn't change the meaning.

The first 'que' in that sentence is grammatically necessary; you wouldn't be able to write or say "*mais il ne sait pas ce c’est que de vivre sur une île isolée".

Comment: BTW, am I the only one who gets a feeling the second sentence stresses a little more the *effects* that living alone on and island has on the speaker?

Answer (score 4):

First, let's note and set aside the "on purpose" redundant structure, which is often used as a way to put emphasis on something, like in :

> Je choisis David. ("neutral" expression)
>
> *C'est* David *que* je choisis. (emphasis on the object)
>
> *C'est* moi *qui* choisis David. (emphasis on the subject)

Regarding the meaning nuance, very litterally, « Ce que *ça fait* » **(personal experience / subjective and perceptive)** is indeed not the same as « Ce que *c'est* » **(universal nature / objective and definitional)**.

Comment: Hi. So does the sentence "mais il ne sait pas **ce que ça fait** de vivre sur une île isolée" suggest that the speaker lives / once lived on such an island and is speaking from personal experience?

Comment: Hard to say without more context. But in any case it hints at the difference between what someone could imagine about this experience and the real thing.