# Signification de « que d'agir »

Tags: usage, conjonctions

Y a-t-il des différences entre les phrases ci-dessous ?

> C'est un crime d'agir ainsi.

et

> C'est un crime que d'agir ainsi.

Comment: In short, the addition of "que" is optional here and arguably a bit on the formal side.

Comment: Je crois que ce `que` est un simple [explétif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explétif) : il ne prend part ni à la grammaire, ni au sens de la phrase.

Comment: This has already been asked [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26428/what-is-the-function-of-que-in-the-phrase-que-de-infinitive-here) although ΥΣΕΡ26328's correct answer hasn't been accepted by @con-gras-tue-les-chiens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the first is more contemporary, the second more formal, even stilted.